# Solve for simple monotonically increasing polynomial

Tags: polynomials

What would be the most programmatically efficient way of solving an equation that looks like:

x + x^2 + x^3 + ... + x^N = y

There is never any coefficients, and Y will always positive and known.   I need to solve for X (where X is always positive).   N can be any number specified by my user.

I can do a 'brute force' sort of guessing algorithm where I can pick 0 and Y as starting points for X, half it, see where the Y lands, and repeat until I have gotten down to an acceptable amount of error, but this seems to be far less than ideal.   Is there a better way?

Thanks for any help!

Mark

Answer (score 0):

You can speed up calculations considerably by rewriting your equation as $(x - x^{N+1})/(1 - x) = Y$ and then calculate $x^{N+1}$ in $O(\log(N))$ multiplications by using successive squaring (e.g. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring ). Other than that I don't think there's any better way to find the solution other than searching for it and approximating it to whatever accuracy you desire; however there are typically fast methods like Newton's method (see e.g. http://www.analyzemath.com/calculus/applications/newtons_method.html ) for finding the zero of an equation if you know the derivatives (which you can compute efficiently given the formula above). In your case the function you want to find the zero of is $f(x) = (x - x^{N+1})/(1 - x) - Y$ where $Y$ is considered a fixed constant.